# Prove that hypergeometric random variable can be written as sum of dependent, identically distributed Bernoulli random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $X \sim \text{Hypergeometric}(N,k,n)$, prove that $X$ can be written as
$$
X=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i,
$$
where $X_i \sim \text{Bern}(k/N)$ and are dependent on each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start, surely $X_1\sim Ber(\frac{k}{N})$ for all $N,k$. Now we assume $X_i\sim Ber(\frac{k}{N})$ for some $i\geq 1$ and all $N,k$. Conditioning on the first draw, we know for any $N,k$
\begin{align*}
        \mathbb{P}_{N,k}(X_{i+1}=1) &= \frac{k}{N}\mathbb{P}_{N-1,k-1}(X_i=1)+(1-\frac{k}{N})\mathbb{P}_{N-1,k}(X_i=1)\\
        &= \frac{k}{N}\frac{k-1}{N-1}+\frac{N-k}{N}\frac{k}{N-1}\\
        &= \frac{k}{N}.
    \end{align*}

So by induction we have for all $i,N,k,X_i\sim Ber(\frac{k}{N})$.